# Strip extra quotes from python list

Tags: python

I'm retrieve some data from a web API, but the retrieved records comes with extra quotes I need to remove; `result = ['"A1","Location1"', '"A2","Location2"']` What is the most efficient way to do this for a large datasets, say 10000 items so that I end up with something like this:

```
result = ["A1","Location1", "A2","Location2"]
```

Comment: Does every single one of the items have extra quotes?

Comment: yes. `['"A1","Location1"', '"A2","Location2"']`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear based on your description. In your example, the `result` list originally contains exactly two items, `'"A1","Location1"'` and `'"A2","Location2"'`. In your output, it contains four, `"A1"`, "`Location1"`, `"A2"`, and `"Location2"`. That's not just removing `'` characters, but also splitting strings. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If each and every item of list `result` is a comma-separated string of "quoted" sub-items (not containing commas within a sub-item), you can easily make a new list `clean` as follows:

```
clean = []
for item in result:
    subitems = item.split(',')
    clean.extend(si[1:-1] for si in subitems)
```

If your constraints are more complicated (quotes may or may not be there around eadh sub-item, a quoted sub-item may contain commas, etc, etc -- I can't just blindly guess right on every detailed constrain you didn't let us know about!-) the task will be proportionately harder, perhaps involving regular expressions, or worse... but we won't know until and unless you edit your Q to specify **very** precisely what, *exactly*, you have to deal with!-)

Answer (score 0):

Another not great (little dirty) but working solution is to use `ast.literal_eval` with `repr`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

result = ['"A1","Location1"', '"A2","Location2"']    
literal_eval(repr(result).replace("\'", ""))

['A1', 'Location1', 'A2', 'Location2']
```

Answer (score -1):

Use python's built in [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). It does this automatically.

Comment: Elaborate? Detail? I couldn't find anything in there that would do this without a lot more code.

Comment: Data that is imported by the csv module can be entered into a list where elements are split by commas, giving your desired result.